# Google Cloud Endpoint performance

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

What is the performance of Google Cloud Endpoints?  In my case a large blob is being transferred.  Size is anywhere from 1MB to 8MB.  It seems to take about 5 to 10 minutes with my broadband speed being about 1Mb upload.

Note this is being done from a Java client calling an endpoint.  The object being transferred looks like this:

```
public class Item
{
   String type;
   byte[] data;
}
```

On the java client side, the code looks like this:

```
Item item = new Item( type, s );
MyItem.Builder builder = new MyItem.Builder( new NetHttpTransport(), new GsonFactory(), null );
service = builder.build();

PutItem putItem = service.putItem( item );
putItem.execute();
```

Why does it take so long to send one of these up to an endpoint?  Is it the JSON parsing that is slowing it down?  Any ideas on how to speed this up?

Comment: Well, in cases like that, I prefer to upload my blob using the [Blobstore API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Uploading_a_blob).

Comment: In this case, our java app is running on a device.  The device produces a lot of data that we stick in a "blob" and upload to GAE via an endpoint.  The endpoint puts the blob in a "queue" which a backed processes (pulls out data and puts in various databases) at a later time.  The reason we used an endpoint is because these devices can be behind firewalls and I assumed the endpoint was a RESTful type web service that works over HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Endpoints is just a wrapper around HTTP requests made to Java servlets (you mention java on client, so I'll make the assumption of java on the server).

This will introduce a very small, fixed, overhead, but the transfer speed of a large blob should be no different whether you are using endpoints or not.

As noted by Gilberto, you should probably consider using Google Cloud Storage (GCS api is slowly replacing the blobstore API).  You can use it to upload directly to storage and remove the burden on your GAE app.

Comment: The reason we didn't use GCS directly is because the java app runs on a device that may be behind a firewall.  From my understanding, an endpoint was basically a web service that worked over port 80 (or 443) and that would reduce firewall issues.

Comment: Uploading to GCS (using or not the Blobstore API) uses HTTP(s) as well. It's just a byte[] upload, the same way clients use to upload photos, avatars, files to Dropbox/Google Drive and so on.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that.  I'll give GCS a try.  In actuality, our backend unpacks the blob and sticks various items in GCS.  I'll try doing that directly from the Java client.

Comment: I tried uploading the file with a straight servlet request.  Seems faster, although one time it did timeout (>60 seconds).  Maybe my internet connection went down for a bit.  I assume the servlet circumvents JSON.

I like the servlet better than direct GCS (from a java client) because the servlet storse the blob in GCS and creates a task in the Task Queue.  The task will process the blob, which may take a while.

Comment: I wouldn't say the servlet circumvents json - servets can be used with any type of content including json.